# Combining Worksheet_Change events in vba code

Tags: excel, vba

I require some help in combining two Worksheet_Change events. Event 1 will reformat the cell to the correct postcode format & event 2 will apply the proper function. How can i combine event 1 & 2 in order for both to work at the same time?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

**Event 1**

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error Resume Next
    
    If Intersect(Target, Range("K17")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}\s[0-9][A-Z]{2}"
        If Not .test(Cells(17, 11)) Then
            Cells(17, 11) = UCase(Left(Cells(17, 11), Len(Cells(17, 11)) - 3) & " " & Right(Cells(17, 11), 3))
    End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**Event 2**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change2(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or Target.HasFormula Then Exit Sub

    On Error Resume Next

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F7;K7")) Is Nothing Then

        Application.EnableEvents = False

        Target = StrConv(Target, vbProperCase)

        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: Can't you just copy the **If** block from the second sub to the end of the first?

Comment: Wouldn't this just be mixing in multiple if conditions? Or why not just call two individual macros?

Comment: @DonR As you can probably see, VBA is not my strong suit and i'm having difficulty in applying your suggestion. How would this look?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just split into two independent macros that each run during the Change event? The below might work. I'd be careful about doing `.cells.count` as that can be a lot if you delete an entire column or a wide range of data.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call macroFirst(Target)
    Call macroSecond(Target)
End Sub

Private Sub macroFirst(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    
    If Intersect(Target, Range("K17")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}\s[0-9][A-Z]{2}"
        If Not .test(Cells(17, 11)) Then
            Cells(17, 11) = UCase(Left(Cells(17, 11), Len(Cells(17, 11)) - 3) & " " & Right(Cells(17, 11), 3))
    End If
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub macroSecond(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or Target.HasFormula Then Exit Sub
        On Error Resume Next
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F7;K7")) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target = StrConv(Target, vbProperCase)
            Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: one can use `Target.CountLarge` to address the potential issue with `.Count` alluded to.

Comment: @PGSystemTester Thank you for the suggestion :) I've made the suggested changes however i'm still experiencing some issues. 'macroSecond' seems to work fine however when making chances in cell K17, the postcode will return in the below format;

XX00                            XXX

The spacing will continue to grow unless i stop the macro. Also, the below is highlighted after debugging;

`Application.EnableEvents = True`

Comment: Hi @Owen4512, sorry you're having issues. You should probably consider having enableevents set to false for the entire procedure. Also, I realize you don't know any better, but it's considered a little bit of bad form to ask a question, and then ask subsequent questions without accepting an answer. I'm pretty sure this  proposal resolves you're original question, so if you wouldn't mind hitting the accept button, it'd be appreciaated. If you have additional questions, you should again post it but make it verry specific to the issue (see how to ask a question). Good luck.